# angularjs: why ng-click doesn't seem to evaluate {{}}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In a ng-repeat tag, I have a ng-click which contains a code to be evaluated as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="stage in stages" class="selectable stage stage{{stage.stage}}" ng-click="changePage('plantStages/{{stage.id}}')">
```

Though in the safari inpector I see the code is evaluated as expected as follows…

```
<div ng-repeat="stage in stages" class="selectable stage stage6" ng-click="changePage('plantStages/floraison')">
```

…a click on the tag goes to unevaluated link as follows:

```
.corn.page.html#/plantStages/{{stage.id}}
```

Here is the changePage in the controller:

```
$scope.changePage = function(page) {

    var url = "kws.corn.page.html#/"+page;

    console.log("Change page "+page+" with url "+url);

    document.location.href = url;
};
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you show your changePage function?

Comment: Sure. I added it in the main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ng-click` is an Angular directive, you don't need to interpolate `{{}}` inside it:

```
ng-click="changePage('plantStages/' + stage.id)"
```

The above show work and is the preferred way.

It is true that the inspector shows the interpolated value, but this is too late in the Angular `$digest` cycle for the `ng-click` to work.